# Best way to add a method to Sylius Model

Tags: symfony, sylius

For my custom shipping calculator I require access to all products in the cart. The method `Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\Shipment::getShippables()` gives me acces to all unique items, but I need to know how many of each of them have been ordered.

I'd like to implement the method `getSingleShippables()` that will not filter out duplicates.

What would be the best way to implement this? Do I really have to overwrite the Shipment model as explained in [Overriding Models](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwiKuciI9J7IAhWOsh4KHavBDhE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FSylius%2FSylius-Docs%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fbundles%2Fgeneral%2Foverriding_models.rst&usg=AFQjCNGvn9rs9wJ2_9F1-4CUbfIKntHbAg) to implement a custom Shipment class or is there a simpler way to do this? I don't need to change the model, just add a 'getter method'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easier way of doing it, you have to follow the instructions in 'Overriding Models' => Extend Sylius class, add your method, and set the model to your new class in config.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.